# How LiveData observable handles Room query asynchronously?

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

According to Docs:

> Room doesn't support database access on the main thread unless you've called allowMainThreadQueries() on the builder because it might lock the UI for a long period of time. Asynchronous queries—queries that return instances of LiveData or Flowable—are exempt from this rule because they asynchronously run the query on a background thread when needed.

I want to know how the LiveData observable do works in the background and get wrapped objects asynchronously?

Comment: Just wondering but for what purpose do you want to know this? If you're curious about the internals then you can read the source code https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/lifecycle. If not then the magic that happens underwater is not relevant for us developers.

Answer (score 1):

LiveData it is all about main thread (ui), when you are creating your dao class, some thing like this:

```
@Dao
public interface DaoExample {

    @Query("select * from example")
    LiveData<List<ExampleModel>> getAllModels();

}
```

Under the hood room creates all needed stuff, some thread for background processing, live data for posting the latest data from table and so on. All this logic encapsulated inside dao/database. When you will insert a new row, room will save it (worker thread) then notify all observables stream (ui thread).

Comment: We need concurrency via RxJava or Coroutines